# XML Signature over XML with existing signature

Tags: java, xml, apache, xpath, xml-signature

I want to sign a XML string that looks like this:

```
<Foo>
<ds:Signature Id="REC">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod />
    <ds:SignatureMethod />
    <ds:Reference>
       <ds:Reference URI="">
         <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
           <ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>
          </ds:Transform>
         </ds:Transforms>
       <ds:DigestMethod>
       <ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    <ds:Reference /> etc.
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue />
  <ds:KeyInfo />
  <ds:Object />
</ds:Signature>
</Foo>
```

So that it adds another signature (with the corresponding digestvalue and signaturevalue) and it should look like this:

```
<Foo>
    <ds:Signature Id="REC">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod />
        <ds:SignatureMethod />
        <ds:Reference>
           <ds:Reference URI="">
         <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116">
           <ds:XPath>not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>
          </ds:Transform>
         </ds:Transforms>
           <ds:DigestMethod>
           <ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
        <ds:Reference /> etc.
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue />
      <ds:KeyInfo />
      <ds:Object />
    </ds:Signature>
    <ds:Signature Id="PAC">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod />
        <ds:SignatureMethod />
        <ds:Reference>
           <ds:Transforms>
           <ds:DigestMethod>
           <ds:DigestValue>[DIGEST VALUE OF ALL THE PREVIOUS XML]</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
        <ds:Reference /> etc.
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue />
      <ds:KeyInfo />
      <ds:Object />
   </ds:Signature>
  </Foo>
```

The java code that makes my transform is:

```
_TRANSFORM = "not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)";
XPathContainer xpathC = new XPathContainer(doc2);
xpathC.setXPath(_TRANSFORM);

Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc2);
transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116",xpathC.getElement());
signature.addDocument("", transforms);
```

What XPATH expression should I use to get a digestion of the whole XML and not just "Foo" (like I did with the previous one)?

So far Ive tried:

- not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature[@Id='PAC'])
- (ancestor-or-self::Foo and not (ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature[@Id = 'PAC'])) or ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature[@Id = 'REC']
- not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature[@Id='PAC']) or (ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature[@Id='REC'])

...with no luck.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature[@Id='PAC']) is correct for the XPATH to grab all the XML except the current signature (in this case the one that has an attribute 'Id' with a value 'PAC') I found out I was misfeeding the XML and it had different values.